# Javascript Map - Remove item by key and update values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, ecmascript-6

I have a map

```
 const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set("10/10", 0);
myMap.set("10/11", 1);
myMap.set("10/12", 2);
myMap.set("10/13", 3);
myMap.set("10/14", 4);
```

and I need to remove one item by key and update all the values of the next items.

For example, if I remove the item with key "10/12", the map has to be:

```
console.log(myMap);
/*
   {
     "10/10": 0,
     "10/11": 1,
     "10/13": 2,
      "10/14": 3,
    }
 */
```

Decreasing the values which are > the removed item value by one. Any ideas?

Comment: can you not have this in an array rather than an object, thats essentially what you are trying to mimic

Comment: I can't. I am making refs to make operations in a big complex list in O(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
const obj = {
   "10/10": 0, 
   "10/11": 1, 
   "10/12": 2,
   "10/13": 3,
   "10/14": 4,
}

const toRemove = "10/12"

let i = 0;
const newObj = {}
for(const property in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && property !== toRemove){
        newObj[property] = i;
        i++;
    }
}

console.log(newObj);
```

EDIT:

Version using Map:

```js
const obj = new Map();
obj.set("10/10", 0);
obj.set("10/11", 0);
obj.set("10/12", 0);
obj.set("10/13", 0);
obj.set("10/14", 0);

const toRemove = "10/12";

let i = 0;
const newObj = new Map();
for(let [key, value] of obj){
    if(key !== toRemove){
        newObj.set(key, i);
        i++;
    }
}

newObj.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key + ": " + value));
```

Comment: I'm not used to Map but i tried to write a working snipped using them @ConchiBermejo

Answer (score 0):

You split it to stages like so:

```js
const obj = {
  "10/10": 0,
  "10/11": 1, 
  "10/12": 2,
  "10/13": 3,
  "10/14": 4,
}

const key = "10/12";

const index = Object.keys(obj).findIndex(k => k === key);
const entries = Object.entries(obj);
const values = Object.values(obj).slice(index, -1);
entries.splice(index, 1);

const res = entries.reduce((acc, [key, value], i) => {
  if(i >= index) {
    acc[key] = values[0];
    values.shift();
  } else {
    acc[key] = value;
  }

  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```